# Android client tell Syn & receive Rst Ack

Tags: android, tcp, mqtt

I'm working for an App Android and I need my phone was always connected to my server MQTT...

But my phone can lost his connection(Tel :[FIN;ACK]; Serv:[FIN;ACK];Tel:[ACK]); after that, when he send a [SYN] message for connect it to the server MQTT, the serveur send an [RST,ACK]... And this while the service of my app is in activity.

In my case , i MUST to re-launch my server if i want my phone can be reconnect, but, i can't reboot my server (multi-phone possible, and i need real-time performence).

There is there a possibility to connect my phone without reboot my server?

Thank's for time.

Best regard

Guillaume

Comment: Expecting near real time network performance in a mobile environment is not feasible, there will always be time when the phone is not available as it shifts connection speed (LTE to HSPA to Edge) or is just out of coverage. 

You are never going to be able to short cut the TCP socket close logic.

Comment: thanks, i know real time is impossible but i need to compete with a dect système (sms) and i can't cut all phones for rescue one of them ... 
I can't do nothing via the phone?

Comment: Given the MQTT portion should all be running as a service (no network on forground threads) subscribe to the network state broadcast messages from Android, use these to tear down the connection and rebuild as needed

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is similar to the one I had.  The connection was half closed.  See http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37490/Detection-of-Half-Open-Dropped-TCP-IP-Socket-Conne  for details.

The way I solved this was to i) add keep alive msgs, every 5 secs. from the phone to the server and ii) have the server close the connection if there was no incomming data for 15sec.  See http://www.forward.com.au/pfod/CheapWifiShield/index.html and www.pfod.com.au

MQTT includes keepAlives (PING request msgs) so you only need to modify your client to specify a short keepAlive interval
see http://www.hivemq.com/blog/mqtt-essentials-part-10-alive-client-take-over
 to have the MQTT server to more quickly close the connection once it stops getting your data or keepAlive msgs.

Although the above link states
"**The broker will close the previous connection to the same client (determined by the same client identifier) and establishes the connection with the newly connected client**. This behavior makes sure that half-open connection won’t stand in the way of a new connection establishment of the same client."

So you should not be having this problem at all !!!